# R speed up sapply

Tags: r, performance, apply, text-mining

I've got the following script in a loop:

```
number_of_rows_similar_addresses <- as.data.table(cbind(
    distinct_similar_addresses,
    sapply(distinct_similar_addresses, function(x) {
        length(similar_addresses[Original_Address == x]$people_names) / length(unique(similar_addresses[Original_Address == x]$people_names))
    })
))
```

The problem is that it slows down considerably the loop.

The data looks like this:

distinct_similar_addresses:

```
"U 2 5 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"       
"U 1 3 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"                            
"U 1 11 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"                            
"U 1 33 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"                           
"U 1 2 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"                            
"U 1 3 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"                            
"U 1 5 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"
```

similar_addresses:

```
    people_names,Original_Address,Numbers,street_Name,street_type,post_code,suburb,PO,UID
Giuseppe Conte,U 1 3 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC,1,TIMPERLEY,ST,5469,NICHOLLS,,
Giuseppe Conte,U 1 3 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC,TIMPERLEY,ST,5469,NICHOLLS,,
Mario Pertini,U 2 5 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC,TIMPERLEY,ST,5469,NICHOLLS,,
Mario Pertini,U 2 5 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC,5,TIMPERLEY,ST,5469,NICHOLLS,,
```

The script is assessing if the address is referring to a unit or a single house.
Is there any way to perform this task faster?

I'm adding a result set and an explaination so that what it does become more understandable.

Result set:

```
   distinct_similar_addresses      V2
"U 2 5 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"   2
"U 1 3 TIMPERLEY ST NICHOLLS VIC"   2
```

The code is just counting the number of names associated to a single row of address.
Indeed if the address is repeated it means that it's referring to a unit otherwise it's a single house.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible given the sample data. Can you please double-check? I also don't understand what you mean by *"The script is assessing if the address is referring to a unit or a single house."* What are you trying to achieve? Can you include your expected output for the sample you give?

Comment: I've changed the datasets and add a result set.

Comment: both the two datasets are data.table

Comment: Your last two sentences would be solved by `similar_addresses[, .N, by = Original_Address]`. I suggest you study the data.table vignettes.

Comment: Btw., please learn to provide a reproducible example. Your data cannot be imported without errors (because columns are missing in some rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gregor,
This is probably better:

```
 x <- similar_addresses[, .N, by = Original_Address]$N
 y <- similar_addresses[, length(unique(people_names)) , by = Original_Address]$V1
 number_of_rows_similar_addresses <- cbind(unique(similar_addresses$Original_Address), x/y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the data inconvenience guys and thanks to Roland for the help.

This is the solution

```
  x <- similar_addresses[, .N, by = Original_Address] %>% select('N')
  y <- similar_addresses[, length(unique(people_names)) , by = Original_Address] %>% select('V1')
  number_of_rows_similar_addresses <- cbind(unique(similar_addresses$Original_Address), x/y)
```

Comment: Since you're using `data.table`, and especially since you don't need `x` and `y` to be data tables (vectors are fine) you might prefer the syntax `[, N]` to replace `%>% select('N')`. Or `$N`.